# Disable autofocus on dialog window when I click on close tab in SublimeText

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-3, window-focus, dialog

I have `Sublime Text 3` installed on `Windows 7`.

When I push on `Ctrl-W` shortcut or click on mouse on tab's close button, then mouse pointer moves automatically on 'Yes' button of Windows dialog box (y/n/cancel).
[image]

I'm pretty sure, that setting it's somewhere on the level of the Windows.

How can I disable this option of autofocus?

Comment: Is this happening in Sublime Text 3 only or other dialog boxes as well? You may have the [mouse pointer Snap To](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/755-mouse-pointer-snap-default-button.html) option enabled. You can disable that in mouse properties and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @MC10 I added clarification to the body of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Snap To mouse feature is turned on. To turn it off, open the Start menu and search for "Mouse", then open the Mouse Properties.

[image: Snap To]

Go to the Pointer Options tab and the Snap To section. Uncheck the box for **Automatically move pointer to the default button in a dialog box**.